# How to include custom modules in pyinfra?

Tags: python, provisioning, pyinfra

I'm using [`pyinfra`](https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/index.html) to provision some files.  I would like to know the best place to put custom modules.

**Example**

Given a custom fact that returns `True` if a system is not headless:

```py
class HasGui(FactBase):
    default = list
    command = 'ls /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop || true'

    def process(self, output):
        return output
```

**Questions**

Where do I put this?  I imagine I can code this snippet directly into an "operation" file, but what if I want to reuse this code in several modules?  How do I abstract this into a separate module or access it from the API?

While [data can be shared across modules](https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/deploys.html#group-data), the recommended [layout](https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/deploys.html#layout) does not appear to easily permit custom modules to hook into the API.

**Approaches**

- I've tried to make a separate task-level module, but it is not recognized when invoked at command-line.
- A last resort may be adding the path to `sys.path`, but I'd prefer a cleaner option.

Answer (score 2):

This [bug](https://github.com/Fizzadar/pyinfra/issues/296) suggests custom facts can be detected from a top-level `config.py` file located [next to "deploy" files](https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/examples/client_side_assets.html?highlight=config%20py).

**Code**

A custom fact coded into the config (optional).  See also a sample [layout](https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/deploys.html#layout):

```py
# config.py

from pyinfra.api import FactBase


class HasGui(FactBase):
    default = list
    command = 'ls /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop || true'

    def process(self, output):
        return output
```

*Note*: the trailing `|| true` keeps pyinfra from erroring out on fails.  Failures seem to be handled internally despite the continuation.

When a custom fact subclasses `FactBase`, it is added to a [facts index](https://github.com/Fizzadar/pyinfra/blob/38033a35321eeb4344ccb9f0549eff14123be4d6/pyinfra/api/facts.py#L76).  You can access them via [snake-cased attributes](https://github.com/Fizzadar/pyinfra/blob/38033a35321eeb4344ccb9f0549eff14123be4d6/pyinfra/api/facts.py#L72):

```py
# tasks/operation.py

from pyinfra import host


if host.fact.has_gui:
   # Insert operation
...
```

**Demo**

Run in command line.

```py
> pyinfra @local tasks/operation.py
[@local]   Successful: 1   Errors: 0   Commands: 1/1

> pyinfra @<server> tasks/operation.py
[@local]   Successful: 0   Errors: 0   Commands: 1/1
```

Answer (score 1):

In actual version, for me, it works like this:

**base:** /home/pyinfra

i have a **subdir** (custom/facts) with custom facts and ops (and `__init__.py` file):

for example **/home/pyinfra/custom/facts/FileFacts.py**

```
from pyinfra.api import FactBase

class FileExists(FactBase):
    '''
    Returns if file exists (true/false)
    '''
    __filepath = ""
    def command(self, path):
        """ Checks if app exists via linux ls command """
        self.__filepath = path
        return 'ls {0}'.format(path)

    def process(self, output):
        # ls should return the path itself if it exists
        if str(output[0]) == self.__filepath:
            return True
        return False
```

Then in my task i can import and call it via

```
from custom.facts.FileFacts import FileExists

if host.get_fact(FileExists, "/etc/app/config"):
     logger.info("File already exits!")
else:
     logger.info("File does not exist!")
```

(dont hang me if the code itself is imperfect, although helpful input is appreciated, its sufficient for my case)

Comment: Looks like a great example on passing args to a custom fact.